# Replacing warped floor of bathroom vanity

Tags: bathroom, water-damage, vanity

I have a built-in vanity with double sinks in one bathroom.  There was a leak in the p-trap that went on for quite a while.  It soaked through the floor of the inside of the vanity and has warped it. I'm thinking that to replace it with some plywood, I will cut the floor out with a jigsaw leaving a ledge around the perimeter.  Or can someone who has done this before suggest a different method?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you plan, but maybe add a center support system, criss cross 1x4's under the bottom. No easy way to do it. Other option, besides replace while vanity, remove the vanity and slide the old bottom out and slide a new one in.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with a kitchen base cabinet that had a sink mounted.  After measuring and cutting the 1/8" plywood (the original floor still provided support), I had to cut the plywood down the center in order to get it in around the vertical door stop, dishwasher, & plumbing.  I left the original floor in place and just put the new plywood down over it.